# JavaScript: How to add a structure inside a JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json

**[Updated the parent and child structures]**

I have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
{
    "case":{
        "steps":{
            "step":[{
                "tasks":{
                    "task":{
                        "fields":{
                            "field":[{

                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

I also have a smaller structure that looks like this:

```
"entry":{
    "name":"XYZ"
},
```

I would like to add 2 copies of the smaller structure into the larger one at the location `case.steps.step[0].tasks.task.fields`

Should this be possible?

Comment: fields is a map, what keys should the two copies have?

Comment: Hi @fafl, this would be a case of inserting two copies of the "field" map and they would be identical (except that the value in the "name" attribute could change if needed)

Comment: shouldn't `fields` be an array instead then?

Comment: An object cannot have two properties with the same name.

Comment: sorry all, you guys are right, I think that may be part of my problem

Comment: I have now corrected the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the job:

```
var biggerStructure = JSON.parse(biggerJsonString);
var smallerStructure = JSON.parse(smallerJsonString);

biggerStructure.case.steps.step[0].tasks.task.fields.field.push(smallerStructure);
biggerStructure.case.steps.step[0].tasks.task.fields.field.push(smallerStructure);

var result = JSON.stringify(biggerStructure);
```

BTW: fields should be an array not an object if you are trying to add multiple objects to it, also field itself cannot be added to the fields mutliple times because of having the same name.

Then the final result will look like this:

```
{
    "case":{
        "steps":{
            "step":[{
                "tasks":{
                    "task":{
                        "fields":{
                            "field":[{
                                {
                                    "name":"XYZ"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"XYZ"
                                }
                            }]
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

case.steps.step[0].tasks.task.fields is an object, for it to contain two copies of field, it needs to be an array like

```
    {
    "case":{
        "steps":{
            "step":[{
                "tasks":{
                    "task":{
                        "fields":[

                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
 };
```

and this can then contain multiple entries of the smaller object field

```
case.steps.step[0].tasks.task.fields.push({"field":[{
                                            "name":"XYZ"
                                              }]});
```